# Hide content in android-webview without onPageFinished()

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, android-webview, android-view

I have a website and I am linking it to my application. I don't want  my logo to be  displayed  twice in webview from website since my app is already desplaying it. I've searched on stackoverflow everywhere it is recommended to use  onPageFinished(). I want to know is there any  other way by which i dont have to wait for page to finish loading and i can right away hide the logo part?
Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of overriding WebViewClient's onPageFinished, you can override WebChromeClient's onProgressChanged and suppress the logo there:

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
        view.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
            //if element exists, hide element
            "})()");
    }
});
```

Note that this method will run a number of times.  It's an inelegant solution but is the best alternative to onPageFinished that I've found.

Comment: Thanks Logan. it helped i was using WebViewClient and it worked but when i go back or pressed back it stopped working. Your answer saved a lot of time for me.